# SQL Server: exclude records whose name column matches values in a 2nd exclusions table

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I have a table that contains names of doctor's offices (Providers) that I want to return a list of.  If any of these office names contain any keywords found in a 2nd table (Keywords), I want to exclude that Provider record from being returned in the list.  I have a query that works fine, however my problem is...

I need to match WHOLE words in the Provider's name to the keyword, in order to exclude it.  If a keyword is merely a portion of a word contained in the doctor's office name, that record shouldn't be excluded. I'm not sure how to do this.

Here's an example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Keywords') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
     DROP TABLE #Keywords
END
GO

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Providers') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Providers
END
GO

CREATE TABLE #Keywords (KeywordId INT, Keyword varchar(50))
CREATE TABLE #Providers (ProviderId INT, ProviderName varchar(100))

INSERT INTO #Keywords(KeywordId, Keyword) VALUES (1, 'ACUPUNCTURE')
INSERT INTO #Keywords(KeywordId, Keyword) VALUES (2, 'CHILD & ADOLESCENT PSYCHIATRY')
INSERT INTO #Keywords(KeywordId, Keyword) VALUES (3, 'Ent')
INSERT INTO #Keywords(KeywordId, Keyword) VALUES (4, 'VA')

INSERT INTO #Providers(ProviderId, ProviderName) VALUES (111,'Family Practice of Pennsylvania')
INSERT INTO #Providers(ProviderId, ProviderName) VALUES (222,'Dr. Smiths Acupuncture')
INSERT INTO #Providers(ProviderId, ProviderName) VALUES (333,'Patient First')
INSERT INTO #Providers(ProviderId, ProviderName) VALUES (444,'Chicago Child & Adolescent Psychiatry')
INSERT INTO #Providers(ProviderId, ProviderName) VALUES (555,'Manhattan Family Practice')
INSERT INTO #Providers(ProviderId, ProviderName) VALUES (666,'Dr. Levys Oncology VA')

SELECT * FROM #Keywords
select * FROM #Providers

SELECT p.* 
FROM #Providers p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   #Keywords k
                   WHERE  p.ProviderName LIKE CONCAT('%', k.Keyword, '%'))
```

In the above sql, any provider's offices that contain any of those 4 values in the #Keywords table, should be excluded.  Therefore, since ProviderId's 222, 444 & 666 have matching keywords, they should be excluded and I should return the following 3 records:

- 111, Family Practice of Pennsylvania
- 333, Patient First
- 555, Manhattan Family Practice

My problem however, if you run that above script, you'll notice only **ONE** record is returned.  This is because ProviderId 111 contains "VA" in "Pennsylvania" and ProviderId 333 contains "ENT" in "Patient".

How can I re-work my query to ensure my keywords match a **WHOLE** word from a Provider's office name rather than just a portion of one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare whole words only - so keywords like 'Ent' aren't matched within a word.

Does the following work for you by including a space either-side of the keyword and the same with the name:

```
where not exists (
  select 1 from #Keywords k
  where Concat(' ',p.ProviderName,' ') like Concat('% ', k.Keyword, ' %')
)
```

[Example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4460831dd60fd3c852603360f8e2738d)

[image]